# How to set a default parameter for a vector <string> for use in a default constructor within a class?

Tags: c++, string, parameters, vector, constructor

For example, a class named Table, with its constructor being: 
`Table(string name="", vector <string> mods);`

How would I initialize the vector to be empty?

Edit:
Forgot to mention this was C++.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is C++?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
Table(string name="", vector <string> mods);
```

if you want vector to be empty inside constructor then

```
mods.clear();
```

or

```
mods.swap(vector<string>());
```

In case you want as a default parameter:

```
 Table(string name="", vector<string> mods = vector<string>());
```

Like any other default parameter.

Comment: Ahh thanks! I kept trying things like vector <string> mods(0,"") and many other variations. Wouldn't have guessed this at all!

Comment: Caught your message before you edited it, this method works vector <string> mods = vector<string>() and just vector mods = vector() complains about needing a template argument.

I'm glad I saw the first message because I probably wouldn't have figured out to put the template argument in both sides of the assignment.

Comment: If by any chance you want your argument `vector<string> mods` to be of `reference` then you must use `const` in such cases, because `C++` doesn't allow temporary variables to be associated with the `reference`.

Answer (score 11):

To add to the other answer: If you're using c++11, you can use the universal initialization syntax to shorten the default parameter declaration for a vector to the following:

```
Table(string name="", vector<string> mods={});
```

Comment: way better than other options.