# C++ Default argument for vector<int>&?

Tags: c++, arguments

I have a function,

```
void test( vector<int>& vec );
```

How can I set the default argument for vec ?
I have tried

```
void test( vector<int>& vec = vector<int>() );
```

But there's a warning "nonstandard extension used : 'default argument' : conversion from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'std::vector<_Ty> &'"

Is there a better way to do this ? Instead of

```
void test() {
    vector<int> dummy;
    test( dummy );
}
```

Regards,
Voteforpedro

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
void test(const vector<int>& vec = vector<int>());
```

`C++` does not allow temporaries to be bound to non-const references.

If you really to need to have a `vector<int>&` (not a `const` one), you can declare a static instance and use it as a default (thus non-temporary) value.

```
static vector<int> DEFAULT_VECTOR;

void test(vector<int>& vec = DEFAULT_VECTOR);
```

But beware, because DEFAULT_VECTOR will (can) be modified and won't reset on each call ! Not sure that this is what you really want.

---

Thanks to [stinky472](https://stackoverflow.com/users/374980/stinky472), here is a thread-safe alternative:

Instead of providing a default value, you might as well overload `test()` with a zero-parameter version which calls the other version:

```
void test()
{
  vector<int> vec;
  test(vec);
}
```

Comment: +1 but I think it should be pointed out that 'test' would generally not be thread-safe were it to modify this 'DEFAULT_VECTOR'. It might be tedious, but I'd strongly recommend writing two functions for such needs (one can reuse the other): void test() {vector<int> temp; test(temp); }

Comment: As a side note, there is a hacky way of getting a reference to a temporary if you can use some method on the latter that returns such a reference to itself... e.g. `operator=`. So, `void test(vector<int>& vec = vector<int>().operator=(vector<int>()));` should work (the lifetime of the temporary is unaffected here and will remain sufficient to handle the call). But please don't do it :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't understand why the DEFAULT_VECTOR should be static. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 8):

I find it questionable for a non-`const` reference argument to have a default value. What is this supposed to mean?

Commonly, a function taking a non-`const` reference means "I might change the argument". If the argument is *optional* why no pass a (non-`const`) pointer? That way, when callers don't want to pass an arguments, they can pass `NULL`.
(See ***[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c/2139254#2139254)*** for more information on how to pass function arguments.)

**Edit:** Well, and of course, there's also *overloading*. Just add another overload which doesn't take this argument.

Comment: @DeadMG: Are you referring to my broken grammar sub-system?

Comment: Would I do something like that?

Answer (score 7):

You could just make pass a pointer to a vector and initialize it to NULL

```
void test( vector<int>* vec = NULL );
```

Comment: Didn't see this answer, buried down here. But this was the solution that solved my problem for a recursive function other than using static.

Answer (score 5):

I know this question was asked in 2010 but for C++11 you can do it like this:

```
void test( vector<int>& vec = {}) {
      // Awesome code here
}
```

As pointed out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23435832/3458969).

Comment: This has the same meaning as `void test( vector<int>& vec = vector<int>() );` as in the question, which is illegal due to attempting to bind a temporary to a non-const reference. In the answer you link to, it is not a reference.

Answer (score 4):

We cannot initialize mutable references to temporaries. Only const references allow this. What you are after is most likely this:

```
void test( const vector<int>& vec = vector<int>() );
```

Aside from avoiding undefined behavior, this makes the most sense logically and from a const-correctness perspective. If you wanted 'test' to modify the original vector being passed to it, you would not have been able to sensibly provide a default value. Thus it's obvious you are using 'vec' here for read-only purposes and should therefore make it a const reference.

Comment: You cannot initialize mutable references to temporaries directly, period. A temporary won't bind to a reference-to-non-const - if you try that, it's not U.B., it's ill-formed input (i.e. compiler error). VC++ lets you do this, but rightly notes that it is a language extension.

Comment: @Pavel ah good point! I've seen nasty compilers that allowed this behavior like MSVC and past versions of CodeWarrior where the code built but crashed. I will modify the post accordingly for accuracy. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked almost 10 years ago. But for anyone finding its solution now, I've got exactly that for you. I basically have three different methods:

```cpp
void test(vector<int>vec = vector<int>(10, 0){//definition}
```

This can be used if it has to be if the default vector has a given size with a common initialiser value.

```cpp
void test(vector<int>vec = vector<int>{1, 2, 3, 4}){//definition}
```

This can be used if it has to be if the default vector has a given size with a different initialiser values.

A different approach could be to define a global vector object as:

```cpp
vector<int> globalvector;
```

(initialised or uninitialised) and the passing this object as default value as

```cpp
void test(vector<int>vec = globalvector){//definition}
```

An important benefit of the last one is that it gives more control over the default value itself as functions can be used to assign values to this `globalvector` before control reaches the `test()` function. Another benefit is that (as far I've yet found), if the function involves passing by reference, this works just as fine as:

```c
void test(vector<int>& vec = globalvector){//definition}
```

unlike the former two.